# Getting error when using FormattedMessage inside a module: Error: [React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, tsconfig, react-intl

I have a monorepo which exposes a TypeScript module, which is consumed & used by a React TypeScript project.

When the module inserts arbitrary React elements to the virtual DOM - everything works as expected, including when I try to use React Router (which was initially problematic but I was able to fix that).

However, when I try to use react-intl, via `FormattedMessage`, I get the error:

```
Error: [React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object. <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry.
```

Which is especially annoying as I see this printed in the console logs:

```
The above error occurred in the <Context.Consumer> component:
    in FormattedMessage
    in h2
    in div
    in Loading (at App.tsx:11)
    in IntlProvider (at App.tsx:8)
    in App (at src/index.tsx:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.tsx:8)
```

(note the `IntlProvider` wrapping `Loading` - which is the element that uses `FormattedMessage` which can't find `IntlProvider`).

I imagine this is somehow related to versioning, or having 2 instances of React / React DOM / IntlProvider, but I have no idea to how solve this, and I have spent quite a lot of time trying everything I could think of.

For what it's worth, here's what I use:

- TypeScript - for both module and project
- Webpack to pack the module, where I declared React, ReactDOM and react-intl as `externals` and added them as `peerDependencies` rather than direct dependencies
- `create-react-app` for the project

I was able to create a minimal repro repository, here's how to repro my issue:

```
<cd somewhere>
git clone https://github.com/chakaz/repro-repo .
cd repro-lib
npm install
npm run build:dev
cd ../project
npm install
npm run start
```

Anyone has any idea? Tons of thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your above way in order to make it work, you have to delete `node_modules` in your `repro-lib` dir cause it will install dependencies in both dirs.

So in order to resolve problem of `monorepo`, I'd like to suggest you use `yarn`'s workspace functionality as described carefully here: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/

To summary, it's a great functionality to help working with multiple workspaces by just only `yarn install` once.

Here are a few steps to make your repo working:

- Put `package.json` at the root level of the project with following content:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": ["project", "repro-lib"]
}
```

- Go to `project` dir and replace following line in `package.json`:

```
"pf-common": "file:../repro-lib"
```

to

```
"pf-common": "1.0.0"
```

- Finally, just go back to root top level install deps again:

```
yarn install
```

That's it! Now you can re-run your application to see how it works.

NOTE: In terms of having interest in monorepo, `lerna` is also great tool comes to help by  providing great CLI.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you! I was stuck on this for waaaay more time than I'd like to admit.

Out of curiosity, as this indeed solved my issue - why is there an error with react-intl but otherwise other react elements (that use react and react-dom) work ok?

Comment: As I think the issue was we had 2 instances not only `react-intl` but also `react` as well so then they were separate which ended up they didn't understand each other.

Comment: But then - how did the "other" `react`, the one used by the library for which I never called `ReactDOM.render()`, worked?

Comment: Personally having two react instances can't create too much problems apart from having a big bundle as you build. The real problem was `react-intl` which doesn't work in terms of having more than one instance.